# Remove folder in git repo?

Tags: git, gitignore

I have a folder for my virtual environment on my local that were pushed to my git repo before I set up my .gitignore file.

How can I remove the folder from the git repo but leave it on local?

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer here:

For single file:

```
git rm --cached mylogfile.log
```

For single directory:

```
git rm --cached -r mydirectory
```